# plutus-playground-server exits with with network error

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

When starting the plutus-playground-server in a nix-shell on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine (ref. step 4 in the [plutus setup instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13112LHG9vVvNUs40oZSqZ-DF6_yFiT_SJZ2NaEmjMM4/edit)), it terminates with the following error:

```
Interpreter ready
plutus-playground-server: Network.Socket.socket: unsupported operation (Address family not supported by protocol)
```

Coincidently, when attempting to start a daedalus wallet on this machine after upgrading from 4.5.2. to 4.6.0, the node crashes due to what appears to be an ipv6 issue (ref. [If the ipv6 is disabled on the system, the node crashes on boot #3449](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3449)). I'm wondering now whether these issues are related?

I believe I have the latest tools and libraries installed: ghc version 8.10.4.20210212, cabal version 3.6.2.0, nix version 2.5.1.

If the issue in Github is related, there's some speculation about NordVPN, which I use on that machine: Here's some details:

```
    /etc/sysctl.conf
    
    # Disable IPV6 to prevent IPv6 leaks with NordVPN 
    net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.tun0.disable_ipv6 = 1

> ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:d5:47:25:6d:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 49116sec preferred_lft 49116sec
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:82:ef:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:82:ef:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:95:7a:3c:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: can you provide output of `ip addr show`?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].